# Model design for a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm building an application that is based on a calendar and (with basic functionality expected from a calendar).

As the calendar will have such a fundamental part of the application I don't want to rely on any gem but build the calendar myself.

I don't know which route to go: to have a day-model representing each day with a unique record (that events can reference by day_id) OR render the calendar "on the fly" based on a Date class (and events would then reference the date).

In short: What model design would be the most efficient to render a calendar?

Comment: Maybe just a Calendar model (if you need more than 1 calendar with different configuration (like number of displayed days, opening days of a week, etc)), and an Event model parent of several models like: `class Appointment < Event` & `class RomanticDate < Event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a model at all.  The following code below will do the trick.

Grab the code from https://gist.github.com/RichIsOnRails/5535564 and drop it in a helper, use like so (haml below, so adapt it to meet your own needs.)  Note that i'm rendering events in this calendar, but you don't have to.

```
= calendar @date do |date|
  .text-left=date.day
  - if @events_by_date[date]
    - @events_by_date[date].each do |event|
      .event=event.title
```

I will do an article on my website in the near future that goes over this in detail.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something specific about the days you would like to model, you may be able to just have an events model, with each event having a date field.  This approach is simpler and I think preferable.  Since there are a practically infinite number of dates, one big advantage of this approach is that you won't need to manage all the logical inconsistencies of keeping a finite subset of dates in your database.

Even if you find a need for a day model, you can do this without tying the model to the database, and thus avoid having a record in your database for every possible date.  This might be useful if you want a method that tells you if a day is a work day, or if you want to find a collection of days.  For more on how to make a model that doesn't require a database table behind it, see this stackoverflow question: [Tableless model in rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275496/tableless-model-in-rails-3-1)